# Why to wrap JS "window" into a self-calling function before calling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working in a codebase recently where there's a number of javascript files, partially angularJS, jQuery, and other libraries. It's been around for a bit, and I'm curious why a particular approach was used for so many of these extension methods or controllers in AngularJS.

So, every time a new AngularJS object is created, it's wrapped in a self-calling function:

```
(function (w) {
  w.app.controller('ctrlName', function ($scope, $ngJSdependency, myOwnDependency) { 
   w.GlobalFunctions.exampleCallGlobalFunction();
   $scope someData = w.GlobalData.someData;
  }); 
})(window);
```

And for the life of me, I have no idea why. I've noticed no function difference between removing the self-calling function and replacing every reference to `w` with `window`. Is there a downside to making those changes and replacing everything with `window`? It feels much cleaner, and works better with my IDE tools as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) four advantages to that strategy in older code that doesn't use modern modules, three really minor ones and one fairly useful one (but only related to the function, not the `window` part):

1. `w` is slightly shorter than `window`. :-D
2. By making `w` a local within that function call, it's found in the local environment when it's referenced, rather than the JavaScript engine having to look for `window` in the local environment, not find it, and go out to the outside environment to find it.
3. The `window` global on at least some browsers (I have to check the spec to see if it's specified) is an accessor property, which means that in *theory*, every reference to it is a function call. So `const w = window;` calls that function once and remembers its return value, whereas using `window` everywhere (in theory) calls the function repeatedly. But function calls are ***really*** fast in JavaScript.
4. (Not directly related to passing `window` into the function.) The function provides a private scope for putting other things that don't need to be accessed outside the function.

#4 is probably the most useful, and as I mention above it's not really related to the `window` aspect, you could do the same thing without the `window`/`w` thing.

In modern environments you'd get #3 by using modules, and if you wanted #1 and #2 you'd do `const w = window;` or similar.

Comment: Thank you much! :) I'm unsure of the costs associated with #2, but I'll probably look at it and see that it might make sense to use `const w = window` (or _w since more searchable). I've also started some research for modules to see how we can use them with ngJS - will be good to adopt some of that syntax before any attempts to migrate to Angular!